# register_globals doens't work

Tags: php, ini, register-globals

I changed hosting service and when I try to enable `register_globals`in `PHP.ini`my website behaves in a strange way. Each time I click on a page it downloads a page with this error:

> Directive 'register_globals' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown
>   on line 0

How can I enable register_globals directive? I know it is not sure but I should replace a lot of things

Answer (score 3):

**DON'T DO IT**. There's a reason why this directive was removed. Source [Using Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

**Warning
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.**

So wherever you had `$magicalVariable`, now you can do something like this:

- quick and dirty but not very safe: `$magicalVariable = $_GET['magicalVariable']`
- even better `$magicalVariable = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'magicalVariable', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`

Rule no.1: Never trust user input!